# What is an action command that is set by setActionCommand?

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener

In [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/RadioButtonDemoProject/src/components/RadioButtonDemo.java) Swing example code I encountered a setActionCommand method. Java's reference only tells that it "sets action command for this component". What is an action command and why do I need to set it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, `JButton` redirects the specified action command to the `ButtonModel`. Here's the method that forwards to the `ButtonModel`, with comment.

```
   /**
     * Sets the action command string that gets sent as part of the
     * <code>ActionEvent</code> when the button is triggered.
     *
     * @param s the <code>String</code> that identifies the generated event
     * @see #getActionCommand
     * @see java.awt.event.ActionEvent#getActionCommand
     */
    public void setActionCommand(String s)
```

So in your `ActionListener` when you get an `ActionEvent` you can check the `getActionCommand()` to distinguish which button was clicked.